# How to get the value returned by a stored procedure called from python in SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pyodbc

I need to check the returned value from a stored procedure on SQL server 2008 R2.

```
 import pyodbc
 sql_str  = """
                DECLARE @return_value int 
                SET @return_value  = -1 
                INSERT INTO [my_database].[dbo].[my_table] 
                EXEC @return_value = [my_database].[dbo].[my_stored_procedure] 
                if @return_value <> 0  
                BEGIN 
                    EXEC sys.sp_addmessage 60000, 16, ' test sp returns wrong code !  ' 
                        RAISERROR (60000, 16, 1) 
                END  
               """
sql_str_connect_db = " DRIVER={SQL server};SERVER={my_server};DATABASE={my_db};UID=my_id;PWD=my_password "
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(sql_str_connect_db )
cursor_test = cnxn.cursor()
cursor_test.execute(sql_str)
cnxn_test.commit()
```

But, I got error:

pyodbc.Error: ('HY007', '[HY007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Associated statement is not prepared (0) (SQLNumResultCols)')

And, how to check the value of "@return_value" in python ?

After searching , I cannot find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just select it like this in your SQL:

```
SELECT @return_value AS return_value
```

Then use your cursor to fetch the records:

```
rows = cursor_test.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row.return_value)
```

Regards,

-Tim